# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Civi\\Setup' not found on install

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install the CiviCRM plugin in wordpress, but never get to see the install page. When I want to go to "Install CiviCRM" button beneath the wp-admin-Dashboard it aborts with "critical error".

It is Debian 11.6 and everything from the repositories: WordPress 5.7.8, CiviCRM 5.33, MariaDB 10.5, PHP 7.4

Apache error log shows:

```
[Thu Mar 23 19:06:50.237128 2023] [php7:error] [pid 886] [client 172.16.0.10:46166] PHP Fatal error:
Uncaught Error: Class 'Civi\\Setup' not found in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.admin.php:138
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Admin->run_installer()
#1 /usr/share/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#2 /usr/share/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action()
#3 /usr/share/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action()
#4 /usr/share/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php(10): require_once('/usr/share/word...')
#5 {main}
    thrown in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.admin.php on line 138, referer: http://172.16.0.92/wp-admin/index.php
```

I did check that things mentioned at CiviCRM requirements page are in place.

I also tried chowning everything relevant to www-data without success.

What else could I think of?

Comment: Civi 5.33 is from 2 years ago. Use a newer version: https://civicrm.org/download

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue.
Wordpress 6.2.2
Civicrm-5.61.4

Can someone point me to where setup.php gets loaded to define this class?

Fatal error: Uncaught Error:
Class "Civi\Setup" not found in XX/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.admin.php:248
Stack trace: #0 XX/civic/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Admin->run_installer('')
#1 XX/civic/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#2 XX/civic/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 XX/civic/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action('toplevel_page_c...')
#4 {main} thrown in XX/civic/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.admin.php on line 248

Comment: hi - this is not an Answer - do you not have enough reputation to add as a comment?

Comment: correct! I've never used this before

Comment: it seems that SE forces you to fire this as a new ticket and then reference this one - even though I can see the risk of your new ticket being marked as duplicate. I will convert this to a Comment if there are no other options